# Простейший код, помогите разобраться. Python

Tags: python

А общем, я начинающий, не могу разобраться.
Есть список:

```
visits = [[1, 30], [41,90], [221, 280], [311, 330]]
```

На самом деле, значения списка совершенно не важны, нужно осуществить проверку на пересечение списков в списке visits

То что сделал я, но это очевидно не верно:

```py
for visit in visits:
    if ((visit[0] < (visits[visits[1]]) or (visits[visits[0]])) and (visit[1] > (visits[visits[1]) or (visits[visits[0])))]:
        print('Ошибка')
```

Объясните пожалуйста, как реализовать такой функционал.

Comment: @Духсообщества что не так, почему вы отменили мою правку ?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе какой результат вы ожидаете получить для списка `visits` и уточните пожалуйста вопрос. Вопрос о пересечении __элементов множеств__ (списков) или о пересечении __интервалов__?

Answer (score 1):

если вопрос о нахождении пересекающихся **интервалов**, то я бы решал его так:

```
from itertools import combinations

visits = [[41,90], [221, 280], [311, 330], [30, 50], [300, 320]]

def is_overlapping(a, b):
    return min(a[1], b[1]) - max(a[0], b[0]) >= 0

res = [[a, b] for a,b in combinations(visits, 2) if is_overlapping(a, b)]
```

---

результат:

```
In [30]: for x in res:
    ...:     print(x)
    ...:
[[41, 90], [30, 50]]
[[311, 330], [300, 320]]
```

PS данное решение будет также работать для *неупорядоченного* списка интервалов

Comment: Я думаю, при уровне квалификации ТС  -  "itertools" -  это слишком. Кстати, он так и не ответил на вопросы про то, как трактовать его вопрос.

Comment: @passant, по поводу использования "itertools" - мое мнение - учиться никогда не поздно. По поводу уточнения - судя по __коду в вопросе__ речь все-таки о пересечении списков

Comment: - согласен. Наша цель тут помочь новичкам учиться. То-ли инструментам, то-ли умению корректно и однозначно формулировать вопросы. Даже не знаю, что важнее.

Comment: @passant, IMO важнее показывать наиболее идиоматические решения для __грамотно сформулированных__ вопросов ;)

Comment: По поводу пересекающихся интервалов находил недавно [эту тему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap). Можно добавить как ссылку, если в основном об этом данный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
visits = [[1, 30], [41,90], [221, 280], [311, 330]]
intersection = False

for i in range(1, len(visits)):
  if visits[i][0] < visits[i-1][1]:
    intersection = True

print(intersection)
```

Comment: не будет работать верно, если строка идет не по порядку, например
visits = [[41,90], [1, 30], [221, 280], [311, 330]]

Comment: @Karpetz в примере тс они идут по порядку

Comment: А кто вообще сказал, что списки - это интервалы???  По-моему, надо было слелать "поиск пересечения списков". А это вовсе не одно и тоже. Итак - либо вы знаете нечто, что недосказал ТС,либо ваше решение решает совершенно другую задачу.

Comment: @passant я сделал для формата, указанного в примере. Отсюда не следует, что это решение другой задачи или что я знаю что-то недосказанное

Comment: Ваше решение строго для конкретного набора данных.  Хотя ТС явно пишет даже  "На самом деле, значения списка совершенно не важны,". Поменяйте два списка местами и посмотрите, будет-ли работать ваша программа.

Comment: @passant из "На самом деле, значения списка совершенно не важны," в общем случае следует, что у задачи нет решения, так как там могут быть не только числа. Так как уточнений по этому поводу не было, я принял ограничения из примера, а не придумывал что-то своё

Comment: @user393643 "так как там могут быть не только числа."- ну и как, будет ваша программа работать в этом случае? И почему в таком случае у задачи "нет решения"? "Пересечение" - это вполне определенный математический термин. И даже, если там будут строки, пересечение может иметь место, а может и нет.  Но это не говорит о том, что "нет решения".

Comment: @passant, `значения списка совершенно не важны` != `так как там могут быть не только числа` ! Это ваша интерпретация

Comment: @passant не будет, я и говорю, что не пытался сделать её рабочей в выдуманных случаях. "Нет решения" в рамках того, что приведено в вопросе. Как определить пересечение `[1,5]` и `['1','5']`? Про это ничего не сказано в вопросе.

Comment: @MaxU -  вы ошиблись. Про "не числа" написал не я. Но мое решение, предполагающее "пересечение" в теоретико-множественном смысле, будет работать и в таком случае.

Comment: @passant, пардон, не прочитал все комменты. Но я тоже считаю, что, судя по коду в вопросе, речь идет о пересечении списков

Comment: @MaxU "значения списка совершенно не важны != так как там могут быть не только числа ! Это ваша интерпретация" - нет, не моя, я такого не писал. Я написал "из "На самом деле, значения списка совершенно не важны," в общем случае следует, что у задачи нет решения, так как там могут быть не только числа"

Answer (score 0):

Универсальное решение, которое работает про любом порядке следования и количестве элементов в списке.
Результат - все элементы списка, которые хоть как-то пересекаются.

```
visits = [[1, 30], [41,90], [221, 280], [30, 63], [311, 330],[41,90,55], [311, 330, 280],[41]]
vis_sets=[set(x) for x in visits]
for i,set1 in enumerate(vis_sets):
    for set2 in vis_sets[i+1:]:
        if len(set1.intersection(set2))!=0 : 
            print(list(set1),list(set2))
```

Результат - только **пары пересекающихся списков**:

```
[1, 30] [30, 63]
[41, 90] [41, 90, 55]
[41, 90] [41]
[280, 221] [280, 330, 311]
[330, 311] [280, 330, 311]
[41, 90, 55] [41]
```